Switching my main breaker, how flush to Meter Box can I get by code?
I am replacing my main lug type load center to a main breaker.  I am confident on the electrical side, but not on the mechanical requirements to stay within code.  I will probably get some of the nomenclature wrong.
Current setup in an indoor breaker that sits about 6 inches below the meter box (that is inside but the face of the meter box breaks outside.  This box is between studs and flush to the drywall and the back of this wall is outside. New breaker will go into same wall cavity.

Question background - Moving the Breaker box to nipple distance away from the meter box.
The new main breaker is a QO and the load center mains wiring location sits much lower than my existing box. I am looking at raising the position of the new box up about the distance of my hands so the existing wiring will reach the the mains lug.  This will put it near flush to the meter box above it.  The following picture shows the conduit to from the top of the existing box to the meter box bottom.

Is it ok to have almost zero clearance between the meter box above and the main breaker below?  I would just replaced the conduit with the minimum-sized conduit nipple.
Original Panel included for comment discussion.



Just a thought on "load center mains wiring location sits much lower than my existing box" : I believe modern load centers can be mounted either end up. Check with the instructions; if your new load center can be flipped, it might shorten the space needed for wiring.

Can you post the label for your existing box? It might be possible to retrofit a main breaker into it...

Thanks for the comments
Triplefault - The replacement is a convertible mains breaker SCH-CQO160M200PC, its the Canadian version of the QO160M200PC1.  The only difference is that the Canadian version has a cover plate for the mains lug.  I am trying to avoid converting it, as I do have some bottom fed circuit as well and it would mess me up.
ThreePhaseEel - Its an old Murry split panel.  I updated the have the photos.  I have some planned new circuits for both 240 and 120 (plug generator interlock), so out of space with this panel

If a house is under NEC 2023, replacing that panel will require one to install a main disconnect outdoors.  So I would advise to install an outside main breaker or Ranch/Trailer Panel before the indoor panel (at which point one could just leave the main panel be -- Rule of Six panels are harmless if there is a main breaker upstream of them). But to answer your question, as close as you want BUT the covers must fit, so you have to be careful with close nipples or box spacer connectors so the covers don't clash.

Thanks Harper, the existing service wires are 200A and the existing meter box is recessed in the drywall with the meter box sticking out of the house siding.  I emailed the Inspectors here to get their opinion if its grandfathered in (since the service wires and above are not being replaced (even with like and kind), my logic is that since the existing service is not replaced, they would be grandfathered in.  I will see what they say....if not then I have to add the panel and then have to look up the rule of six panels (as I do not know it).

@ChucktheDuck -- are you actually in Canada? (there are some Canada-specific things with service equipment that really change the game as to what your options are)  Also, how many new 120 circuits do you have planned?  Finally, where do the disconnected black wires in the existing panel go?

The Canadian box I have has a removable separator ( for the incoming and outcoming wire separation rules). It was also a lug that was bonded somewhere that was not in the us panel. I asked the inspector before I purchased it and he said he had no problem with it because of the CSA matching some us code.

@ChucktheDuck -- as to how many new 120 circuits you're planning for, and where the disconnected black wires in the existing panel go to?

@ThreePhaseEel - I plan to add 4 120v and at least 1 240v device.  I think its the limit for the panel.   The black wires go directly to the meter box, which is embedded in the wall (not surface mount). If the meter was surface mount, I would have no problem installing the external disconnect, as I want to avoid more penetrations in the wall.

@ChucktheDuck -- I was referring to the thinner black wires in the existing panel that look to be not hooked to anything, not the fat black service wires that land on the existing panel's main lugs.  Noted on the circuits, though -- you indeed are pretty well out of space, given your desire for that degree of expansion

@ThreePhaseEel the aluminum cut wires are to the old electric heater. I think gas service was not here originally.

@ThreePhaseEel, spoke with the Inspector yesterday and pointed to the code for WA that allows the external disconnect not be included when the Service and above isn't changed or replaced. (staying 200A, so no changes).
Also the CSA only symbol is good, because they are currently certified to assess UL 67 until 2027.

@ChucktheDuck -- I'd have expected the inspector to require it be a CSAus or cCSAus mark, which'd look like this instead of just a CSA mark (which defaults to Canada-only), but shrug

Quick reminder that comments may evaporate over time; anything that wants to be part of the long-term record should be copied into an answer.

Harper answered the question in the comment section.

as close as you want BUT the covers must fit, so you have to be careful with close nipples or box spacer connectors so the covers don't clash.

I found 2" nipple spacers available, and the covers are on opposite faces in this case.
There are also other issues discussed in the comments.

Harper pointed out that the 2023 NEC requires external disconnects for like and upgrade replacements.


Per conversation with WA State Inspector, WA code does not require when panel service wires are not changed since this is a change before the panel.


ThreePhaseEel pointed out the lack of CSA(usa) markings on the panel, and it may be rejected by the inspector.


CSA listed only main panels should be currently allowed, the following must still remain true (but check with inspector first).
CSA uses CSA  C22.2 No. 29, which calls out UL 67 standards with subset extras (UL 67 is for electrical panels)
CSA remains a Nationally certified lab
Good thread on UL vs CSA:
CSA never had a 42 circuit rule, so previous to 2008 revision, they were not compatible.  That is why this FAQ from 2006 doesn't list the panel I have.
Schneider(Square D) didn't go back for CSA(USA) markings because it would cost extra on an older released device and the panel knockouts are different than the UL/USA model because of different connection requirements on the service side for Canada. I only looked into this because I already purchased this panel for cheap.


That helps explain my questions re: binational panelboard assemblies, thanks for digging up that FAQ
